What did Jesus mean when he stated in Matthew 24:22 that the days would be shortened?
There are many different commentaries and opinions regarding this statement by Jesus. The most widely accepted answer that I have seen by many scholars and preachers is that the 7 years of Jacob’s trouble will actually be shorter that 7. Their reasoning is such that if Jacob’s trouble were to actually last the entire 7 years no one would survive.
What other possibilities are reasonable from the methods available in biblical hermeneutics?

Jesus meant his words, he meant that most Christians would not be saved if that period was not shortened because of the degree of persecution some Christians would have given in, so God had to shorten that period.

"The most widely accepted answer that I have seen by many scholars and preachers is that …". The question should give a direct quotation and citation for at least one of these. In particular, as it stands now I have no idea why anyone would relate Matthew 24:22 to "the 7 years of Jacob's trouble".

The explanation in your own answer is neither clear enough nor detailed enough to be substantiated. But I agree that 'shortened days' could mean that days are depleted by external factors. For example, climate change may cause us to have to do many extra and laborious tasks - just to stay alive. Hence the days will be 'shortened' in the sense that there will be less time, each day, for humanity to spend time and energy on building their own 'utopia'.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a real question, it is the stating of an opinion.

@Nigel J, I added a question at the end to make this relevant to BH. Please reconsider.

Jacob's trouble, if it referred to Jeremiah 30:7, does not specify a period of 7 years. So if the question is based on this conjecture, it should be closed.

Closure? The question is a good question. But the reason for the question is errant. Perhaps a patiently given Answer would restore a correct hermeneutical approach to this question for the Poster. The context of Jesus' statement is the Destruction of Jerusalem in 70 A.D. and not eschatological. (Dispensational teaching has been accused of skewing interpretations.)

What does the scripture state? Matthew 24:21-22 states:

For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not been since
the beginning of the world until this time, no, nor ever shall be.
And unless those days were shortened, no flesh would be saved; but for
the elect’s sake those days will be shortened.

As far as I can tell there are two main approaches to this scripture:
Historical approach: We can considers the historical context of the text. For example, some scholars believe that Jesus was referring to the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70. (See the Benson Commentary or the Pulpit Commentary). In this case, the “days being shortened” could refer to the end of the siege by the Romans.
Eschatological approach: Other scholars interpret this verse as a prophecy about the "End Times" also known as, the "Great Tribulation". This is a period of severe trials and afflictions before the second coming of Christ. Here, the “days being shortened” is God putting a limit to the duration of human suffering.
According the the Enduring Word commentary:

a. Great tribulation, such as has not been since the beginning of the
world until this time: Jesus said that this will be the most awful
time in all history. When we think of the terrible wars, plagues,
famines, and genocide history has seen, this is a sobering statement.
When God pours out His wrath on a God rejecting world, it will be
truly great tribulation.
i. Those who believe that the events of Matthew 24 were all or mostly
all fulfilled in A.D. 70 are in the unenviable position of arguing
that the calamity that befell Jerusalem at that time was the worst
catastrophe of all history. This is not possible to adequately defend
historically. As bad as the catastrophe of A.D. 70 was, there have
been subsequent wars and calamities even worse. This reminds us that
this great tribulation — this time of catastrophe such as has not been
since the beginning of the world until this time — has not yet been
fulfilled.


An interesting question.  I believe the answer lies in this same chapter.
[Mat 24:21-22 ESV] For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, no, and never will be. And if those days had not been cut short, no human being would be saved. But for the sake of the elect those days will be cut short.
What is the great tribulation cut short by by?
I understand the great tribulation to be all the time we have been in since at least 70AD.  But what cuts those days short? After warning us not to be deceived by false christs, it seems that the answer is given in verse 27: For as the lightning comes from the east and shines as far as the west, so will be the coming of the Son of Man.
This will occur on the last day of this world, when dead believers are raised(John 6:39,40,44,54) and unbelievers are judged (John 12:48).  This day is  testified to in the parable of the harvest (Matt 13:24-30), and at this chapter's end, in a parable of Christ's second coming:
[Mat 24:21-22, 27, 46-51 ESV] 21 For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, no, and never will be. 22 And if those days had not been cut short, no human being would be saved. But for the sake of the elect those days will be cut short. ... 27 For as the lightning comes from the east and shines as far as the west, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. ... 46 Blessed is that servant whom his master will find so doing when he comes. 47 Truly, I say to you, he will set him over all his possessions. 48 But if that wicked servant says to himself, 'My master is delayed,' 49 and begins to beat his fellow servants and eats and drinks with drunkards, 50 the master of that servant will come on a day when he does not expect him and at an hour he does not know 51 and will cut him in pieces and put him with the hypocrites. In that place there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.

As I have searched many online sites and engines, I have not found any similar answer to the one that I am submitting here:
The reason Jesus states “And unless those days were shortened, no flesh would be saved; but for the elect’s sake those days will be shortened in” (Matthew‬ ‭24‬:‭22‬ ‭NKJV‬‬) is because there is a specific day, of the entire year, that Jews are made white, refined, and atoned for - the Day of Atonement (Leviticus 16:34), which falls on Tishrei 10, or the tenth day of the seventh month.
Jacob’s trouble of 7 years will begin on Nisan 10, or the tenth day of the first month. Jacob’s trouble would therefore end 7 years later, also on Nisan 10. And 30 days after that would be Iyar 10.
In the book of Daniel, Daniel 12:11 states that many shall be purified, made white, and refined on the 1290th day. Starting at the midpoint of Jacob’s trouble, when the abomination of desolation occurs, there will be 1260 days (3-1/2 years) to the end. There will also be 1290 days (30 days later) when Israel will be “saved”. If Israel is to be saved on that 1290th day, that day would have to be Tishrei 10, the Day of Atonement. However, as stated above, that day corresponds to Iyar 10, the tenth day of the second month.
Therefore, God will shorten the days by 4 hours per day (Revelation 8:12) at the 4th Trumpet. By doing this, the days are shortened, and carrying out those 4 hours in a span of 3-1/2 years equates to exactly 7 months, or 210 days (during Jacob’s trouble there will only be 360 days in a year…not 365). Because of this, Jacob’s trouble will now end on Elul 10 and 30 days later it will be the Day of Atonement, when Israel is finally saved…..30 days after Jacob’s trouble ends.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Forum, Dominic. You might want to research the term "Jacob's trouble." Consider Genesis 34:30 where is says,
"Then Jacob said to Simeon and Levi, 'You have brought trouble on me by making me stink to the inhabitants of the land, the Canaanites and the Perizzites. My numbers are few, and if they gather themselves against me and attack me, I shall be destroyed, both I and my household.'
